# Can you test CDK constructs with Mocha instead of Jest?

Tags: jestjs, mocha.js, aws-cdk

The [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/testing.html) makes it sound like you can only use jest with the cdk. However, our projects currently use mocha. We could use jest for the cdk and keep everything else the same, but we're wondering if anyone has had any luck using mocha to test the cdk.

EDIT:

So far, it seems to have worked with this simple set up:

- installed `ts-node, mocha`
- ran with `mocha -r ts-node/register file.test.ts`

file.test.ts:

```
import { expect as expectCDK, matchTemplate, MatchStyle } from '@aws-cdk/assert';
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as Infrastructure from '../lib/infrastructure-stack';

it('Empty Stack', () => {
    const app = new cdk.App();
    // WHEN
    const stack = new Infrastructure.InfrastructureStack(app, 'MyTestStack');
    // THEN
    expectCDK(stack).to(matchTemplate({
      "Resources": {}
    }, MatchStyle.EXACT))
});
```

Has anyone tried more complicated tests?

Comment: How did this work out for you? I'm working on a new CDK project and use mocha for many other projects. Have you run up against any major gotchas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cdk assert library was written with jest in mind but I couldn't find any classes that will only work with jest so it should work with any test framework since they provide their own expectations function, `cdkExpect`